# How do I know when a Snowflake "preview" feature will make it to "Production" state?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am very interested in both "[Streams](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/streams.html)" and "[Tasks](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/tasks-intro.html)" features in the Snowflake database.

Both have been in Preview mode since June 2019.

Is there a way to know when these are planned for final/production mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should monitor the [Snowflake Release Notes](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/release-notes.html) and specifically the [Preview Features](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/release-notes/preview-features.html).
It is way more likely that Snowflake will let you know when it's done than giving a future date.